# Как получить список пользователей с уровнем доступа Editor?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Скрипт

```
function GetSSMetaData() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('Accesses');
    var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()

    for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
        if (ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue()) {
            ss.getRange(i, 2).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue()).getName())
        }
    }

    for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
        if (ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue()) {
            ss.getRange(i, 5).setValue(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue()).getLastUpdated())
        }
    }

}
```

берет из "С" id и открывает по этому id таблицу, берет название и дату последнего изменения и записывает его в "В" и "Е" соответственно.

Нужно еще получить список пользователей у которых есть доступ к этим таблицам.

Получается вытащить только 1 пользователя с помощью `getEditors()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Серсвис `DriveApp` возвращает класс `File`, у которого есть метод `getEditors()`, возвращающий массив пользователей `{Array.<User>}`. У класса `User` есть несколько методов. Вероятно, вам нужен `getEmail()`

Код ниже помещает в переменную `editors` электронные адреса редакторов, перечисленные в виде строки через запятую:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
var editors = file.getEditors()
  .map(function(user){
    return user.getEmail();
  }).join(", ");
```